# TypeScript + Node.js + Handlebars Import File as String

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, handlebars.js

I'm working with a Node.js app using TypeScript and templating with Handlebars. I'm struggling with getting Handlebars files (`.hbs`) to import *as a string* successfully. The template files are based on a JavaScript template; TypeScript and Node.js attempt to import these as modules and thus throw an error attempting to execute the code. Since `.hbs` files are not standard `.ts`, my goal is to import the file as a string; While I can easily do this using `fs.readFileSync` or `fsPromises.readFile` with `utf-8` encoding or similar and parse the file as a string directly, this is not an option for my use case as I need to `import` the files during compilation. I'm compiling / running the app with `ts-node`, e.g., `mymachine$ ts-node src/index.ts`.

**index.ts**

```js
/// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />

import test from "./templates/test.hbs";

console.log(test);
```

**index.d.ts**

```js
declare module "*.hbs";
// also have tried:
declare module "*.hbs" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

**test.hbs**

```js
// This Handlebars template is to generate some JavaScript / TypeScript code
import axios from 'axios'

console.log("ABC123");
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./@types"
        ],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "files": true
    }
}
```

**Error Thrown**

```
import axios
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have noticed several answers demonstrating how to do this effectively on a client app using Webpack and `raw-loader`, and have personally achieved this successfully with `.md` files as a test case for a React app (via `declare module "*.md"`, then `import file from "./file.md"` returns `file` as a string). However, I'm not sure that these solutions extend to Node.js on the backend.

A simple workaround is to just write the template file as a string in a `.ts` instead of as a raw file in a `.hbs` (see below), but I'd prefer to keep the file as a pure `.hbs` to keep syntax-highlighting, Prettier formatting, and logic encapsulated.

**workaround.ts**

```js
import Handlebars from "handlebarsHelpers";

export const test = Handlebars.compile(`
// This Handlebars template is to generate some JavaScript / TypeScript code
import axios from 'axios'

console.log("ABC123");
`);
```

**workaround-index.ts**

```js
import test from "./workaround";
console.log(test);
```

Any suggestions? The problem seems to be independent of `.hbs`; even using a `.txt` with the same native JavaScript results in TypeScript/Node.js attempting to import the file as a module rather than passing the contents as a string.

Comment: Have tried similar with SQL files: Ended up using fs and readFile. In case you have a loader like webpack, then that could be used to bundle additional files in at compile time.